# Angular - How to properly change Dynamic Generated View on Tab Click?

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently I've been working with Angular and I'm now facing a trouble getting to understand how does ViewContainerRefs work when you have dynamic Views.

I have an exam where based on 2 dropdown selectors, you can create tabs related to the selection (as in the image)

[DropDowns - Dynamic tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiEPd.png)

The code used to create those tabs is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="selectIndexTab($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [label]="tab.Label">
    <div><ng-template injury-host matTabContent> </ng-template></div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

injury-host is a Directive to the ViewContainerRef and selectIndexTab is where buildInjuryComponent method is called.

**TS**

```
createTabIfNotExist(injuryType, CustomeInjuryType, dynamicTabs: Array<TabModel>) {
   let existingTab = dynamicTabs.find(x => x.ExternalId === injuryType || x.ExternalId === CustomeInjuryType);
   if (!existingTab && (injuryType || CustomeInjuryType)) {
  let ntab = new TabModel();
  ntab.ExternalId = injuryType === InjuryType.Custom ? CustomeInjuryType : injuryType;
  ntab.Label = ExamEnums.getInjuryTypeDescription(injuryType);
  if (this.injuryHost) ntab.Component = this.buildInjuryComponent(injuryType);
  this.tabs.push(ntab);
}
```

}

So basically, when you select one of the values on the dropdown list, a tab is added to the array of tabs that is displayed in the first image. Also, when it's added it calls the build buildInjuryComponent based on the selected value and this is where the content should be displayed based on the tab being selected.

```
private buildInjuryComponent(injuryType: any) {
const injuryItem = this.injuryItems.find(
  injuryComponent => <InjuryType>injuryComponent.type == <InjuryType>injuryType
);

const viewContainerRef = this.injuryHost.viewContainerRef;

const injuryCompFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(injuryItem.component);
this.injComponentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(injuryCompFactory);
this.injComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

switch (injuryType) {
  case InjuryType.AnkleInjuryRight || InjuryType.AnkleInjuryLeft:
    (<AnkleComponent>this.injComponentRef.instance).setExamData(this.examData);
    break;
  case InjuryType.Thumb:
    (<ThumbComponent>this.injComponentRef.instance).setExamData(this.examData);
    break;
    case InjuryType.GenericInjury:
    (<GenericInjuryComponent>this.injComponentRef.instance).setExamData(this.examData);
    break;
  default:
    (<SpineComponent>this.injComponentRef.instance).setExamData(this.examData);
    break;
}
```

}

The problem here is that only the first tab selected displays the view, the other one won't show a thing as seen in the image. [Tabs Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaPwf.png) .

I guess the problem relies on the way the viewContainer is being used in the buildInjuryComponent method, but I still can't manage to see how should this be used in order to display the information of both tabs

Comment: Since there are multiple `injury-host` directives present in a DOM at time, your `injuryHost` should be of type `QueryList<InjuryHost>`. Then try to find get the injury host directive which to which you want to add the dynamic component.

Comment: @Ashish injury-host is defined this way export class InjuryDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
Should I be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you can create a minimal stakblitz. i can check.

Comment: It's actually hard since the project has so many dependencies :( . I tried turning injury-host to QueryList but now in the buildInjuryComponent the line const viewContainerRef = this.injuryHost.viewContainerRef; throws an error since it's now a list